# HTML Text Field Restrictions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, contacts

I am new to developing sites, I have created a form with a persons contact details.

In the email text field I would like to only allow email addresses with the character @, if the '@' character is not present, then an error message will be displayed.

Html code for email entry is:

```
<td class="content"><input name="txtEmail" type="text" class="box" id="txtEmail" size="60" maxlength="100" /></td>
```

Javascript to ensure that the field is entered is:

```
function checkShippingAndPaymentInfo()
{
    with (window.document.frmCheckout) {
        if (isEmpty(txtEmail, 'Please enter your email address')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above works but does not have the restriction I require. All I need is validation for the '@' character to be set in the text entry field. Please can someone help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should help you. 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to validate email address using regular expression in Javascript. It will validate the presence of `@` along with other email qualifiers. I use the following snippet from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Comment: by far the best way, there is a lot more to validating an email then just looking for the @ symbol

Comment: Email address checking is *very* tricky, and any method will pass incorrect addresses or reject correct addresses, usually both. The question was specifically about checking the presence of “@”, which is simplistic but in many ways useful.

Comment: So in my case would it be----------- function validateEmail(txtEmail) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(txEmail);
}

Comment: @JUM Yes. Make sure your return statement also has "txtEmail" and not "txEmail"

Answer (score 0):

Replace `type="text"` to `type="email"`

Comment: Even if your answer is correct, it's always better to briefly explain to OP why you think it could solve its problem.